# Can I use PHP scripts in Firefox extension?

Tags: php, firefox-addon

If I put PHP script in the "data" directory can I use it in my Firefox add-on?

Comment: Nope, they require php interpreter to be installed, setup and somehow told Firefox to use them in the correct way.

Comment: What are you trying to make?

Comment: I just try to find out what can I do with addons) So far, nothing concrete)

Comment: When you get an idea let me know I'll get you started.

Comment: Thanks) I see you created many addons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox add-ons can only execute JavaScript. This still leaves you with a few options:

- Rewrite the PHP code in javascript by hand
- Rewrite the PHP code in javascript by hand, using a library like [phpjs](https://github.com/kvz/phpjs) which emulate PHPfunctions in javascript
- Use a PHP-to-JavaScript transpiler to convert the code (might only work for simple code)
- use a PHP interpreter that is written in JavaScript, like [this one](https://code.google.com/p/phype/wiki/ThePhypeProject) and execute the PHP script

(I just googled those links and have no idea how well they work, there probably are better alternatives)

A rewrite of the PHP code is the only clean way in my opinion. Carefully migrating the most basic code with a transpiler might save some time though.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox CANNOT use php in extension directly, unless you indirectly call your php code via XPCOM or other workaround.

Comment: @Haze, why you need to run PHP in extension?

Comment: So far, I'm just trying to figure out what I can do with addons)